# from HTTP to HTTPS proxy server without modify

Tags: node.js, security, https, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm not sure I'm using the right name for what I want, but let's assume I need proxy which transfer HTTP to HTTPS.. (not sure if this is the name needed)

I want to run Node.js server (call it ProxyServer) which receives HTTP requests which aren't destined to this ProxyServer, which means the destination address (or domain, is for some other server (call it RealDestinationServer).
The only change I need to do to the request is to convert it to HTTPS request, instead of HTTP.

the code i have written for the proxy server is:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var fs              = require('fs');
var https           = require('https');
var http            = require('http');
//this is how u create a custom proxy 
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

    proxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
        appLogger.error('something got wrong')
        appLogger.error(err)
        res.writeHead(500, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });

        res.end('Something went wrong. And we are reporting a custom error message.');
    });

    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        appLogger.info('target adddress is: ')
        appLogger.info(req.headers.host)
        // note: external server listen on https on 9999
        proxy.web(req, res, { target: req.headers.host, port:9999 ,ca: [ fs.readFileSync('test-cert.pem') ]});
    });


    console.log("listening on port 7777")
    server.listen(7777);
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
 error:  Error: connect EINVAL 0.0.39.15:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
at connect (net.js:870:16)
at net.js:1004:7
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:64:16)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:83:10)
```

My ProxyServer holds certificates for different external servers in order to execute those HTTPS requests.

1) I user nodejs package from npm, which is http-proxy

2) My external server is an HTTPS server which I created, this server answer to HTTPS requests, and created a self signed certificate. so this server holds the key + cert. note, the server listen on port 9999 for https

3) I created the ProxyServer, using the http-proxy package and the external server certificate when I run my ProxyServer.

So what is the problem? Well, it's not working, but, I think I'm missing something. The documentation of http-proxy and also documentation of all other *proxy* packages never show a scenario that I need.

I need this:

client ---req[ ----> proxy --- [req[**HTTPS**://external_server]] ---> ExternalServer

and back to the client also on the same path.

What am I missing? is what I am looking for is proxy?

Why http-proxy package only show two scenarios:
1) HTTPS -> HTTP
or
2) HTTPS -> HTTPS

What I need is, HTTP->HTTPS
I also notice that in documentation, I to create my httpProxy using "key" and "cert", why do I need a key if I want to authenticate the external server? I only need a ca, not a key or a cert!
anyways, the proxy options I do not provide key or cert, I only provide ca (which is the external server's certificate.)
Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: yes, I need it to be in node.js, but in any case, it  doesn't matter if it is node or NginX, because packages that calls themselves "proxy" suppose to do the same thing as Nginx.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.